# Is there any wiki engine that supports page creation by email?

Tags: email, wiki, mime, wiki-engine

I want to consolidate all the loose information of the company I work for into a knowledge base. A wiki seems to be the way to go, but most of the relevant information is buried inside PST files, and it would take ages to convince people to manually translate their emails one by one (including attachments) into wiki pages. So I'm looking for a wiki engine that supports page creation by email, that is, capable of receiving email (supporting plain text, html and attachments) and then create the corresponding page. Supporting file indexing and looking for duplicates would be a huge bonus.

I tried with [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/), but didn't find what I was looking for. I wouldn’t mind to build my own engine (borrowing a couple of snippets here and there for [MIME decoding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MIME_De_Encode_in_C_.aspx)), but I don’t think is that a rare problem so there is no implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Jotspot and MediaWiki allow you to do this. The latter has support for a lot of plugins, of which this is one. The format is essentially PageTitle@something. Jotspot is a hosted solution where you get your own email address, MediaWiki is self-hosted and you give it a mailbox to monitor for incoming.

Articles are appended to pages if they already exist, or a new page is created if it does not. This does require a degree of discipline for naming conventions, but is great for CC'ing.

We use MediaWiki here and I like it a lot. It has the same flaws as many other Wiki packages (e.g difficult to reorganize without orphaning pages) but is as good if not better than other Wiki packages I've used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I know many of 37 Signals' products support adding data through email.  I use Highrise to keep track of some of my business correspondence, and I'm able to CC or forward emails to Highrise and they get added to the appropriate contact.